# Why register MysqlConnection as Service?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, razor, mysql-connector

I'm trying to learn asp.net core 6.0, and I have a website that I'm working on. I needed a mysql connection in my website. I opened google and started searching. I write a code and it works without any problem;

```
using (var con = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;user=dbuser;password=123456;database=gamedata")) {
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE id=7", con);
    var o = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (o.Read()) {
        Console.WriteLine(o["email"]);
    }
}
```

But in the documentation (not sure it's official). There is a step for registering service. I kept searching and almost every documentation says "do this" without any reason, for example;

```
If using ASP.NET Core, you will want to register a database connection in Startup.cs:

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddTransient<MySqlConnection>(_ => new MySqlConnection(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Default"]));
}
```

Is it a must or an option, why would I do this? And why my code still works fine without this line?

Comment: Do you want every class to hard code a connection string? Or to know where/how it's stored in configuration? What happens when you need to change those details?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I don't plan to create mysql connections for many times, so I do not store connection string anywhere, just write it everytime I use it. If I want to store them, I would probably use static classes.

Comment: Right, so most examples you see will be based around professional use where not repeating yourself repeatedly will be used. If you don't see a personal value in it, so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern is used for [Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Your startup code provides a way (using `AddTransient`) to create a `MySqlConnection` whenever one is needed. Your controllers or models can then access a `MySqlConnection` by receiving one in the class constructor. It's defined as `Transient` so that each object that needs a `MySqlConnection` receives a new one (and so that multiple objects aren't sharing the same `MySqlConnection`).

```cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MySqlConnection _connection;

    public IndexModel(MySqlConnection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
    }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        await _connection.OpenAsync();
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you're not using Dependency Injection, then you don't need the `ConfigureServices` method. Most documentation "says 'do this' without any reason" because it's just assumed that that's how a typical ASP.NET Core 6 web application is authored.

Comment: So if I don't use Dependency Injection and write my code the way I write, will it be a problem?

Comment: If you don't use Dependency Injection, then don't write a `ConfigureServices` method. It won't hurt anything, but it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: I already didn't write ConfigureServices method, the part I share was just a copy of the part of the documentation. But I got the point I think. The method isn't necessary, I can just use MySqlConnector without registering any services.

Comment: @AtahanAtay Correct; I'll add a note to my answer to make that explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add a little Info to Bradley's answer.
One big advantage of the DI is, that you can specify a **scope**:

- transient
- scoped
- singleton

He already included the link to the official documentation.
Bear in mind, this is an ASP.NET core app. In comparison to an plain old console app, these scopes define when code is executed, for example, each time someone visits your website, or only once per server-start. The framework handles the creation of new object instances, so you don't need to call `new` yourself. In some cases, at first, this may seem complicated and unnecessary, but imho, when the project grows, the pattern is very helpful. Simply inject the service you need and let the framework handle the scope, that you define in Program.cs.

Note in simplified .NET 6 Program.cs you simply call:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//...
builder.Services.AddScoped<YourService>();
//or interface
builder.Services.AddScoped<IYourService, YourService>();
```

Ofc it is your decision in how far you want to implement DI. But I'd consider it good practice to learn using it, since in some cases it actually is helpful in maintaining  your resources, like socket management: See [HttpFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests). Which uses an extension method for DI.

Another major advantage imho is, that you can specify an **interface** for DI, and which class to use, when a consumer injects the interface. With that pattern you can easily write different implementations of that interface, and you only have to swap a **single** line of code to change the inject class everywhere.

A real world example would be a service that imports data from a local json for debugging and development, and later when the API is ready, you swap the DI and use a service implementation that calls a REST-API. Another one would be a service that forwards payment information to paypal and you want to swap it for a service that sends it to a credit-card firm.

In your example probably calling `new` yourself or using a transient is good enough. But pay attention, whether an external resource, like an SQL connection is better disposed immediately or preserved for a particular scope. The discussion about [connection pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) is not new, but DI provides a way for you to solve this to your liking.

I find this [tutorial](https://blazor-university.com/dependency-injection/) on DI also quite helpful.